# Stop and change interval of System.Window.Threading.DispatcherTimer

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer, windows-phone-8, intervals

I have the following timer in a windows phone 8 project:

```
private void temperatureTimer()
{
    System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer dt = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
    dt.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1, 0, 0); 
    dt.Tick += new EventHandler(dt_Tick);
    dt.Start();
}
```

My **first** question is: it's possible to stop the timer before it reaches the next tick? Or by other words, it's possible to stop the timer instantly?

**Second** question: I want to change the interval. Do I need to stop it and start it again in order to recognize the new interval? I see there is a interval property but it doesn't let me set the value, only get it.

Comment: You can Stop timer instantly (Immediately after start) and Change Timer interval property It has Get and Set. See the article -http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.interval.aspx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Answer 1:**

Yes it is possible to stop the `timer` immediately. You can stop it by calling its `Stop()` method:

```
dt.Stop();
```

**Answer 2:**

No you don't need to `Stop` the `timer` to change its `interval`. This is how you can set the new `interval` (you've already done the same):

```
dt.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1); // one second
```

When you set the `interval`, it doesn't restart itself, it just follows the new `interval`.

You can see the following link for details:  [DispatcheTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

**Update:**

According to your code to stop the `timer`:

```
private void turnoff(){ dt.stop();}
```

It will not work. Because your `timer` is in another method, so out of that method its scope has been finished, you can not call it in another method. To do this you will have to make global, like this:

```
System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer dt; //declaration outside the method
private void temperatureTimer()
{
    dt = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer(); //initialization inside a method
    dt.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1, 0, 0); 
    dt.Tick += new EventHandler(dt_Tick);
    dt.Start();
}

private void turnoff() //now your this method will work to stop the timer
{ 
    dt.stop();
}
```

Comment: For some reason I can't get it to stop, it keeps running. Maybe I'm doing something wrong? If I call this will it work? `private void turnoff(){ dt.stop();}` The same goes for the interval.

Comment: My bad, I had it outside the method before. Thanks for seeing that. It still doesn't work but at least it seems it's making something. When it reaches `dt.stop` it throws an System.NullReferenceException. Do you know why?

Comment: @sparcopt if you call `turnoff` method earlier so obviously `dt` reference will be null, first call `temperatureTimer` to initialize it, then try to `stop` it

Comment: You can also initialize it at the time of declaration, `System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer dt = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();` then you will have to remove this line `dt = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();` from `temperatureTimer` method. Both ways are correct

Comment: Yes yes, I'm calling `temperatureTimer()` first and then I call `turnoff()` and it still gives me that exception. Same exception if I try to change the interval.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32961/discussion-between-sparcopt-and-shaharyar)